# Why does an N retries failure rate is $(1-x)^N$?

Tags: arithmetic, performance

I read this blog post [Fixing retries with token buckets and circuit breakers](https://brooker.co.za/blog/2022/02/28/retries.html) (by Marc Brooker), which goes through several retry strategies.

For the "N retries" strategy (i.e. on failure, the client makes a maximum of N retries of the call), it explains that:

> [...] If the downstream failure rate is x%, the effective failure rate is $(1-x)^N$, but with significant additional work. At 100% failure rate, the system does 1+N times as much work.

I don't get the $(1-x)^N$ formulation. For example, when x is 100%, then that means we have $(1-1)^N$, which is just 0, so it doesn't make sense.

Can you help me understand this formulation?

Comment: In fact, $(1-1)^N = 0$.

Comment: I wouldn't trust a blogger using the phrase "$x$%" when they mean "$x$". Also, if the probability of failure once is $p$, then the probability of failure $N$ times is $p^n$.